# Python - How to do non-blocking read from PIPE in subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess

I've posted similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368379/python-how-do-i-use-two-threads-for-stdin-and-stdout-respectively-in-subproces) last week and this post reflects my trial and the problem I am facing now.

The program to invoke through Popen is a command line program. I use one thread to read one item from queue and send it to the stdin and get the response from stdout. However it **hangs** in the `proc.stdout.read()`. I did see it works fine with expected output last Friday and then when I did some changes today, it hangs. The change I made is replace `read()` with `readlines()` and use a loop to iterate the results. I am aware that `readlines()` would probably block but when I reversed the code to where it was with `read()` last Friday, it blocks, too. I completely get lost to it now. Any possible causes?

Below is the code to get one sentence from queue and feed it to the java program to get a response:

```
''' below is the code for worker thread. '''
def readQueue(proc, queue):
    print 'enter queueThread.\n'
    global notEmpty
    notEmpty = True
    while notEmpty:
        try:
            sen = queue.get()
            proc.stdin.write(sen.strip())
            res = proc.stdout.read()
            print res.strip(), ' ', sen
            queue.task_done()
        except Empty:
            break
    print 'leave queueThread.'
```

The main thread below is to read each line from a file and put it in a queue for the worker thread to process item by item:

```
def testSubprocess():
    ee = open('sentences.txt', 'r')
    #ff = open('result.txt', 'w')   # print it to stdout first before really write to a file. 
    lines = ee.readlines()
    cmd = ['java', 
           '-cp', 'someUsefulTools.jar', 
           'className', 
           '-stdin',]   # take input from stdin
    proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, bufsize=-1, universal_newlines=True)
    q = Queue()
    for sen in lines:
        q.put(sen.strip())
    readThread = Thread(target=readQueue, args=(proc, q))
    readThread.daemon = True
    readThread.start()
    print 'Main thread is waiting...\n'
    q.join()
    global notEmpty; notEmpty = False
    print 'Done!'
```

Comment: Apologies if I have misunderstood your code and this doesn't work, however I found that I can stop a Pipe from blocking this way. (I don't have a lot of experience with threading in python) After you define the "proc" add this: "fcntl.fcntl(proc, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)" if proc is being defined as type "pipe" this should stop it blocking. you may need to import fcntl.

Comment: @Aphire not sure if I got it right, it seemed "fcntl" is used for linux/unix environment, right? (my working environment is windows)

Comment: Imagine you send a sentence to the java program: how do you know when to stop reading the response: is it *always* 10 bytes or is it *always* a single line or do you want to read until EOF i.e., each process can answer only a **single** question?

Answer (score 1):

The pipes from the subprocess are file like objects.

The method `read()` on these objects reads everything into memory until EOF is reached if you don't specify how much is should read, see doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read.

You have to set the size you want to read if you don't want this behaviour. Try setting it to 1 byte?

The same goes for `readlines()`, see documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines

Comment: Have tried and set the size to read. Problem remains the same. Almost want to give up and turn to [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Some programs might behave differently when executed through `pexpect` as the programs can detect if they are running in a terminal (TTY device). Don't know if Java programs can do this. For example if I run `ps aux` on my system, `ps` detects that the terminal is only 80 characters wide, and shortens the lines accordingly. If we pipe the output into a file (like with subprocess), it will not know what the width of the terminal is, and therefor not shorten the lines.